# Getting viewport height using ExtJS-4X or javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I want to get the height of the viewport using ExtJs or native javascript.

How can i get this height ? I am not using any extjs viewport container.

If its not possible using ExtJs then how can i find the exact height of the view port ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Using javascript i can get the height using 

window.innerHeight

Can some one help in finding out how to get height of view port in ExtJS-4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
window.innerWidth
window.innerHeight
```

in ExtJS you can use `getViewSize( )`

Another plain JS approach is

This function will return any document height (cross-browser) and if the documents body height is less than the viewport height then it will return the viewport height instead. Cause I think your doc is empty at the time you check this should perfectly work for you.

```
function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
```

Comment: hey thanks...ya i got using window object...but if you have idea on how to do it in ExtJs then pls let me knw..Thanks

Comment: I tried using getViewSize()...but it gives error...

to which object this method belongs? and how to use it ?

Comment: @4zh4r You need to run it on a `Ext.dom.Element`. You can find it under the `el` property of a component (after it is renderered) or by calling `getEl( )` on it. So calling `viewportInstance.getEl( ).getViewSize( )` should do it

Comment: i want the height inside Ext.onReady() function and till then none of my element is rendered..
i have an hidden input element in my jsp with id as 'hiddenInp'

i did following but it gave me height as 0

Ext.get('hiddenInp').getViewSize().height

Comment: i am able to achieve what i want to do using 

window.innerHeight

but i want to know how it can be done in ExtJS or what is that I am doing wrong when using ExtJS ?

Comment: @4zh4r Ok, see my edit. And without any ExtJS component created you cannot do it, cause all methods are nested into a private abstract class. Meaning that you can't rely on them.

Answer (score 8):

Using window.innerHeight solved my problem and also the ExtJs way of finding the view port height is as follows -

```
Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height
```